# Excel pull sheet from another workbook SharePoint file: How to pull entire sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to pull the entire sheet from a closed workbook more effectively.

```
='https://mylink/mylink/mylink/mylink/[material_requested.xlsx]material_requested'!A1:Y100000
```

How can I pull the entire sheet(all columns and rows) without just saying `A1:Y100000` because the row quantity change daily?

Comment: Use `$1:$1040000` instead.

Comment: I would use Power Query here. It will expand dynamically as per your data in a given day

Comment: I used "$1:$1040000" and while it captures all the rows it makes endless columns with zeros. My sheet stops at column Y.

Comment: You can try: `=LET(rng,'https://mylink/mylink/mylink/mylink/[material_requested.xlsx]material_requested'!A1:Y1040000&"",IF(ISNUMBER(--rng),--rng,rng))`

Comment: The above code just shows as text in the cell.